# how to check the toggle button state when list is refreshed or re-opening the app

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences, baseadapter, togglebutton

my app contains a list view which is being populated by a spinner value
this list contains toggle button in each row and for customization purpose i have used baseadapter  in list view

i am changing image of toggle button on checked and unchecked
the functionality is going well on toggle button and listview but the problem occurrs when i closes the app and then again opens it it gets refreshed and the toggle state become unchecked and the unchecked image is shown every where

so to solve this i have saved the value of toggle button in shared preferences but now i dont know where to check this in base adapter class  plz help me

the necessary code for this

```
public class DDListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<DataModelDD> listArray;
        int curIndex=1000, pIndex;

        public DDListAdapter(String[] str, String[] str1) {
            listArray = new ArrayList<DataModelDD>();

            for (int i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
                listArray.add(new DataModelDD(str[i],str1[i], " Day Alert on " + str[i],false));    
            }   

        }

        public void DDListUpdate(String[] str, String[] str1){
            listArray = new ArrayList<DataModelDD>();
            for (int i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
                listArray.add(new DataModelDD(str[i],str1[i], " Day Alert on " + str[i],false));    

            }
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listArray.size(); // total number of elements in the list
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {

            return listArray.get(i); // single item in the list

        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {

            return i; // index number

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int index, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
            lIndex = index;
            pIndex = index;


            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lstdd, parent, false);

            final DataModelDD dmFl = listArray.get(index);

            final TextView lbl1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDDate);
            final TextView lbl2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDres);

            lbl1.setText(dmFl.getDDate());
            lbl2.setText(dmFl.getDres());


            final ToggleButton btnlock = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnDAlarm);

            if (dmFl.getdSel()) {
                //selected
                btnlock.setButtonDrawable(a_icon);


            } else {
                //not selected
                btnlock.setButtonDrawable(a_dicon);
            }




            btnlock.setTag(pIndex);
            btnlock.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    if(btnlock.isChecked()){

                        btnlock.setButtonDrawable(a_icon);
                        btnlock.setChecked(true); 
                        dmFl.setdSel(true);

                         Integer position = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();


                         sp = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
                         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                         editor.putBoolean("value"+month+"_"+state+"_"+cday, true);
                         editor.commit();          

                        }


                    else{

                        final String alarmTime = dmFl.getDDate();
                        disableAlarm(buttonView,alarmTime);
                        btnlock.setButtonDrawable(a_dicon);
                        btnlock.setChecked(false); 
                        dmFl.setdSel(false);

                        Integer position = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();

                    }

                }


            });


            return view;
        }
    }


and the data model class
package com.example.dd;

public class DataModelDD {

    private String DDate;
    private String Dres;
    private String ShrStr;  
    private Boolean dSel;

    public DataModelDD(String DDate, String Dres, String ShrStr, Boolean dSel){
        this.DDate = DDate;
        this.Dres = Dres;
        this.ShrStr = ShrStr;
        this.dSel = dSel;
    }

    public String getDDate(){
        return this.DDate;
    }

    public void setDDate(String DDate){
        this.DDate = DDate;
    }

    public String getDres(){
        return this.Dres;
    }

    public void setDres(String Dres){
        this.Dres = Dres;
    }

    public String getShrStr(){
        return this.ShrStr;
    }

    public void setShrStr(String ShrStr){
        this.ShrStr = ShrStr;
    }

    public Boolean getdSel(){
        return this.dSel;
    }

    public void setdSel(Boolean dSel){
        this.dSel = dSel;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do

is

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(settingsTAG, 0);
boolean rb0 = prefs.getBoolean("rb0", true);

if (dmFl.getdSel()||rb0) {
            //selected
            btnlock.setButtonDrawable(a_icon);


        } else {
            //not selected
            btnlock.setButtonDrawable(a_dicon);
        }
```